# What is "studying symmetries without the concept of a group"?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm reading Jost's *Mathematical Concepts*, here:

> [image]

I got curious about this: What is the meaning of "studying symmetries without the concept of a group"? Everytime I head about "symmetry", the word "group" was nearby. Did people tried to study symmetry before group theory? What were their methods?

Comment: The answer should be yes as groups were exactly introduced with the purpose of studying symmetry. In other words, if people were not studying symmetry, we wouldn't have groups either. I guess it's doable though as symmetry plays an important role in physics and many physicist even now don't really use the concept of a group.

Comment: I think the point of the discussion you cite is that you can't study symmetry without doing group theory. Even if you're not using the word "group," you're still studying properties of the symmetry group of some space. The language of group theory just allows us to do so in a systematic and abstract manner.